# Javascript function doesn't repeat itself

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to verticaly align every .class on a site with the help of Javascript. So far I got this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function setContent() {
            var windowHeight = 67;
            if (windowHeight > 0) {
                var contentElement = document.getElementById('center');
                var contentHeight = contentElement.offsetHeight;
                if (windowHeight - contentHeight > 0) {
                    contentElement.style.position = 'relative';
                    contentElement.style.top = ((windowHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2)) + 'px';
                }
            }
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            setContent();
        }
    </script>
```

This works but only on the first element with the ID center. Since I have 6 elements which have to change I changed the code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function setContent() {
            var windowHeight = 67;
            if (windowHeight > 0) {
                var contentElement = document.getElementsByClassName('center');
                var contentHeight = contentElement.offsetHeight;
                if (windowHeight - contentHeight > 0) {
                    contentElement.style.position = 'relative';
                    contentElement.style.top = ((windowHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2)) + 'px';
                }
            }
        }
        $('.center').each(function(){
            $(this).setContent();
        });
    </script>
```

I changed document.getElementById('center'); to document.getElementsByClassName('center'); so it takes all the classes (and yes, I've changed it in the html as well). I've also inserted a bit of code which should repeat the function for every element with class center. Problem is, it doesn't work and I can't figure out where it goes wrong..

Any ideas?

Comment: `contentElement` will contain all elements with the `center` class not only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with these changes:

```
        function setContent() {
            var windowHeight = 67;
            if (windowHeight > 0) {
                var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('center');
                for(var i in elems) {
                  var contentElement = elems[i];
                  var contentHeight = contentElement.offsetHeight;
                  if (windowHeight - contentHeight > 0) {
                      contentElement.style.position = 'relative';
                      contentElement.style.top = ((windowHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2)) + 'px';
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            setContent();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('center')` returns a NodeList containing all the elements with that class name, not a single element. If you use it, then you need to *loop over it*.

You never call `setContent()` though.

You call `$(this).setContent();`. If we assume that `$` is jQuery, then you would have to express `setContent` as a jQuery plugin, and fetch the element from `this` instead of searching the DOM (since you have already searched the DOM with the `$('.center')` call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setContent(contentElement) {
    var windowHeight = 67;
    if (windowHeight > 0) {
        var contentHeight = contentElement.offsetHeight;
        if (windowHeight - contentHeight > 0) {
            contentElement.style.position = 'relative';
            contentElement.style.top = ((windowHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2)) + 'px';
        }
    }
}
$('.center').each(function(){
    setContent(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you can see [document.getElementByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) does not return only one single DOM-Element, instead you get a NodeList of all the Nodes which have the class 'center'.
And as a NodeList does not have the property style, your modifications have no effect.

```
$('.center').each(function(){
    $(this).setContent();
});
```

Here you iterate through all the elements with class 'center', but you are trying to call a function which actually does not exist on those elements, so it has not effect either.

As you are using jQuery i would recommend you to try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setContent(contentElement) {
        var windowHeight = 67;
        if (windowHeight > 0) {
            var contentHeight = contentElement.offsetHeight;
            if (windowHeight - contentHeight > 0) {
                contentElement.style.position = 'relative';
                contentElement.style.top = ((windowHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2)) + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        var centerElements = document.getElementByClassName('center')
        for(var i = 0; i < centerElements.length; i+=1)
            setContent(centerElements[i]);
    }
</script>
```